# golang http parsing header with multiple values

Tags: http, go

How can I obtain value from header that have multiple comma separated values. For instance,

```
url := "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
resp, err := http.Get(url)
field := resp.Header.Get("Cache-Control") // "public, max-age=3600"
```

In this case I want get `max-age` value. I see 2 cases:

- using `strings.Split()`, `Trim()` and etc (I think it's not good idea)
- using `bufio.Scanner` with `SplitFunc` (little bit better)

Any good idea or best practice?

**Edit 1.** Using `strings.FieldsFunc()`

```
const input = "   public,max-age=3000,   anothercase   "

sep := func(c rune) bool {
    return c == ',' || c == ' '
}
values := strings.FieldsFunc(input, sep)
```

Regarding benchmarks

```
BenchmarkTrim-4  2000000  861 ns/op  48 B/op  1 allocs/op
```

**Edit 2.** Using `Scaner()`

So lets benchmark it

```
func ScanHeaderValues(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    // Skip leading spaces.
    var start int
    for start = 0; start < len(data); start++ {
        if data[start] != ' ' {
            break
        }
    }
    // Scan until comma
    for i := start; i < len(data); i++ {
        if data[i] == ',' {
            return i + 1, data[start:i], nil
        }
    }
    // If we're at EOF, we have a final, non-empty, non-terminated word. Return it.
    if atEOF && len(data) > start {
        return len(data), data[start:], nil
    }
    // Request more data.
    return start, nil, nil
}

func BenchmarkScanner(b *testing.B) {
    const input = "   public,max-age=3000,   anothercase   "
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(input))
    split := func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
        advance, token, err = ScanHeaderValues(data, atEOF)
        return
    }
    scanner.Split(split)

    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        for scanner.Scan() {
            // a := scanner.Text()
            // b.Logf("%+v\n", a)
        }
    }
}
```

And result:

```
BenchmarkTrim-4     2000000   861  ns/op  48 B/op  1 allocs/op
BenchmarkScanner-4  50000000  21.2 ns/op  0  B/op  0 allocs/op
```

If you have any other better solution I would like see it.

Comment: Why are `Split` and `Trim`/`TrimSpace` not a good idea?

Comment: @JimB I think I'll get much more memory allocation that I can avoid by using `Scanner`.

Comment: You can't use anything that simply splits on strings, as cache control values can use quoted-string syntax, which would allow a "," inside a value

Answer (score -2):

Nothing wrong with:

```
url := "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration"
resp, err := http.Get(url)
fields := strings.Split(resp.Header.Get("Cache-Control"), ",")
for i, field := range field {
    fields[i] = strings.Trim(field, " ")
}
```

**Edit:** Edit now works if space after comma is missing

Comment: It fails for the valid header value `public,max-age=3600`.

Comment: @MellowMarmot that is correct. I always thought the space is required, but the specs say otherwise (https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2)

Comment: @TheHippo that's not the spec (anymore)

Comment: it'll fail for Cache-Control parameters using quoted-string values, which might contain a comma.